# MySQL not recognizing my HTML form select value

Tags: mysql, forms, pdo

Okay, I've gone around and around on this one, but I'm stumped. I'm a relative beginner with PDO, but I've been researching feverishly for several days without luck.

What I'm attempting is a filter (in this case by speaker name). Everything displays fine without the WHERE filter in my SELECT statement; all the audio files + info from the test db show up just as I want them. And if I insert the WHERE statement with an actual speaker name from the database, that works as expect, i.e. only that speaker's audio is displayed. But I've been unsuccessful making the WHERE statement dynamic from selected form data.

As you can see, the code is a bit of a mess because I've tried the WHERE a number of different ways, including (as you see here) the posted value right in the statement, as well as trying to use bound values (e.g. :speaker_name) or as a more general variable. I'm not generating errors at this point, but I'm not displaying the filtered results either. It basically seems like the script is not seeing the form result at all, but I can't figure out why.

```
    <?php

    include './config2.php';
$speaker = isset($_POST['speaker_name']) ? $_POST['speaker_name'] : false;
    try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,
        $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $speaker  = ( ! empty($_POST['speaker_name']) ? $_POST['speaker_name'] : '');

        if ( isset($_POST['speaker_name'])) {
            $speaker = $_POST['speaker_name'];
        }
        $results = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sermons WHERE speaker_name = '".$_post['speaker_name']."' ");

    $results->bindValue(':speaker', $_POST['speaker_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $results->execute();

        for($i=0; $row = $results->fetch(); $i++){

?>
    <div class="sermon-box">
            <h3 class="sermon-title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
            <p class="date-detail"><?php echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['date_preached'])); ?></p>
            <p class="text-detail"><?php $str = $row['text_book']; $str = substr($str, 3); echo $str; ?> <?php echo $row['text_reference']; ?></p>         
            <p class="speaker">Preacher: <?php echo $row['speaker_name']; ?></p>
            <audio controls>
                <source src="/files/<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
            <p class="download"><a href="/files/download.php?file=<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>">&#9660; Download MP3 <span>(<?php echo human_filesize($row['file_size']); ?> MB)</span></a></p>
        <?php 
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;

        ?>
        </div><!-- end sermon-box -->
```

Here's the form itself:

```
    <?php
        include './config.php';
        ?>
        <form action="sermon-search-action4.php" method="post">
        <?php 
        $smt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT speaker_name FROM sermons ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(speaker_name, " ", -1)');
    $smt->execute();
    $data = $smt->fetchAll();
        ?>
<label for="speaker">Speaker</label><select name="speaker" id="speaker" autocomplete="off">
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <option name="<?php echo $row["speaker_name"]?>" value="<?php echo $row["speaker_name"]?>"><?php echo $row["speaker_name"]?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Comment: Option has not a name attribute. Only the parent select has

Comment: Thanks. That's true, I added it out of desperation, but it wasn't the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php

    include './config2.php';
$speaker = isset($_POST['speaker_name']) ? $_POST['speaker_name'] : false;
    try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,
        $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $speaker  = ( ! empty($_POST['speaker_name']) ? $_POST['speaker_name'] : '');

        if ( isset($_POST['speaker_name'])) {
            $speaker = $_POST['speaker_name'];
        }
        $results = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sermons WHERE speaker_name = '".$_post['speaker_name']."' ");

    $results->bindValue(':speaker', $_POST['speaker_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $results->execute();

        for($i=0; $row = $results->fetch(); $i++){

?>
    <div class="sermon-box">
            <h3 class="sermon-title"><?php echo $row[$i]['title']; ?></h3>
            <p class="date-detail"><?php echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($row[$i]['date_preached'])); ?></p>
            <p class="text-detail"><?php $str = $row[$i]['text_book']; $str = substr($str, 3); echo $str; ?> <?php echo $row[$i]['text_reference']; ?></p>         
            <p class="speaker">Preacher: <?php echo $row[$i]['speaker_name']; ?></p>
            <audio controls>
                <source src="/files/<?php echo $row[$i]['file_name']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
            <p class="download"><a href="/files/download.php?file=<?php echo $row[$i]['file_name']; ?>">&#9660; Download MP3 <span>(<?php echo human_filesize($row[$i]['file_size']); ?> MB)</span></a></p>
        <?php 
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;

        ?>
        </div><!-- end sermon-box -->
```

Instead of using $row['speaker_name'] you should use $data['speaker_name']

```
  <?php
        include './config.php';
        ?>
        <form action="sermon-search-action4.php" method="post">
        <?php 
        $smt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT speaker_name FROM sermons ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(speaker_name, " ", -1)');
    $smt->execute();
    $data = $smt->fetchAll();
        ?>
<label for="speaker">Speaker</label><select name="speaker" id="speaker" autocomplete="off">
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <option name="<?php echo $data["speaker_name"]?>" value="<?php echo $data["speaker_name"]?>"><?php echo $data["speaker_name"]?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Comment: Hm, thanks for the attempt, but when I do that, I get a blank option dropdown on the form page. If I use use $data on name and value of the option but use $row between the tags, I see my proper options again, but still get a blank result.

Comment: Also doesn't work if I change $row to $data in my script's echo statements.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it.

speaker-display.php:

```
    <?php
include './config2.php';
$speaker_name = isset($_POST['speaker_name']) ? $_POST['speaker_name'] : false;
    try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,
        $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $speaker_name  = ( ! empty($_POST['speaker_name']) ? $_POST['speaker_name'] : '');

        if ( isset($_POST['speaker_name'])) {
            $speaker = $_POST['speaker_name'];
        }
        $results = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sermons WHERE speaker_name = ?");
        $results->execute(array($speaker_name));
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sermon Search</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<link href="/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link href="/_ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body class="churchuse">
<?php   for($i=0; $row = $results->fetch(); $i++){

        $found_rows = true;
 ?>
    <div class="sermon-box">
            <h3 class="sermon-title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
            <p class="date-detail"><?php echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['date_preached'])); ?></p>
            <p class="text-detail"><?php $str = $row['text_book']; $str = substr($str, 3); echo $str; ?> <?php echo $row['text_reference']; ?></p>         
            <p class="content-detail">Keywords: <?php echo $row['keywords']; ?></p>
            <p class="speaker">Preacher: <?php echo $row['speaker_name']; ?></p>
            <audio controls>
                <source src="/files/<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
            <p class="download"><a href="/files/download.php?file=<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>">&#9660; Download MP3 <span>(<?php echo human_filesize($row['file_size']); ?> MB)</span></a></p>
    </div><!-- end sermon-box -->
        <?php 
        }
        if (!isset($found_rows)) echo "Sorry, no sermons found for this book.";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;

        ?>

 </body>
```

Search box:

```
    <div class="searchbox">
<?php
        include './config.php';
        ?>
        <form action="speaker-display.php" method="post">
        <?php 
        $smt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT speaker_name FROM sermons ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(speaker_name, " ", -1)');
    $smt->execute();
    $data = $smt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        ?>
<label for="text_book">Search by Speaker</label><select name="speaker_name" id="speaker_name" autocomplete="off">
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <option name="<?php echo $row['speaker_name']?>" value="<?php echo $row['speaker_name']?>"><?php echo $row['speaker_name']?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
</div><!-- end search box -->
```